# Does Batman use Linux?

Tags: dc, batman

While reading a [*Windows 8.1* *tips & tricks*](https://www.itpro.co.uk/desktop-software/21373/windows-81-tips-tricks-13-ways-to-increase-productivity) blog, I came across this conversation in the comment section where they were joking about the possibility of Linux being [Batcomputer's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcomputer) choice of OS. Could it be true? A customized OS perhaps? Could the utility belt be running Java? I've searched for an answer which yielded nothing but some vague description of it being a supercomputer and that was it!

[image: Batcomputer]

Comment: Of course not. He obviously used BSD, Bat Software Distribution.

Comment: “Could the utility belt be running Java?” That's tangential to being on Linux or not. Java can run on Linux, Windows, OS X, and others.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I knew that. I mentioned it as a separate thing, since Java is a common language in electronic devices and such.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I've found one *in-universe* and one *out-of-universe* instance of Batman using an ***actual*** computer (e.g. as opposed to a Hollywood computer with [customised graphic interface](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExtremeGraphicalRepresentation))

### 1960's Batman

The 1960s Batman series used a modified [Burroughs Corporation B205](https://www.starringthecomputer.com/computer.html?c=45).

[image: Burroughs Corporation B205]

The Batcomputer in that case was running the **[CTOS/BTOS Operation System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_Technologies_Operating_System).**

### Comicbook Version - 1990s

The panel below shows that the BatComputer uses seven Cray T932 "plug-in units" to provide backup processing power.

[image: BATCOMPUTER COMPONENTS]

In order to interface with his own BatComputer, Batman must be quite proficient in using **Cray's own unix-based operating system; [UNICOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20220222150048/http://0x07bell.net/WWWMASTER/CrayWWWStuff/prfolderproduct/T90_announce.950222.txt)**

Comment: @bpvxxvqd - It's from [Batman The Ultimate Guide To The Dark Knight](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/107037.Batman), Page 42.

Comment: Valorum  Different from that https://2.bp.blogspot.com/UVOgAFPZMQ1gwEK3QCocpO3cBP5JOnfDuk-yhypHwHwFmoOXf6B2SrvQ3ivVj-PFKOjddyKysA6B-PcRevPDHUixkoxSnCrJG4aj_ZsdMvzXvDTgM4BQFGicFCt1oSEeZfjv4wTuzQ=s1600

Comment: There have been two editions of this book. The "updated" edition has a black pattern underneath the batcomputer; https://i.stack.imgur.com/sizSS.jpg. The version above is simply an edited version of that.

Comment: Please What is the source of this image for batcomputer And who is its designer  https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/casscain/images/3/32/Batcomputer.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100707234137

Comment: @bpvxxvqd - Good question, don't know. Go [ask it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as a question on the site!

Answer (score 74):

Expanding on the answer of @jrg and @Richard, I think we can safely assume that we should consider the question as referring to times beginning from 1980s, since that's when UNIX systems actually appeared on the mainstream user/corporate market. Obviously neither *n*x OS was an option earlier than this rough date due to movie/comix readers/watchers (not to mention creative staff's) perception of the whole computer science; we got mainly blinkenlichten in movies from pre-1980 era due to little recognition of actual computer operating systems' looks.

To sum up:

a) Since we can assume Batcomputer was a mainframe during 1980-1990 era, it's highly probable it was shipped with some custom **UNIX** clone, however it is not unheard of entirely machine-specific systems, especially with high-end machines. He certainly hasn't used **Linux** during that time, because Linux hasn't been created by Torvalds yet.

b) Beginning with ca. 1995, Batman used T932, a most powerful variant of T90 supercomputer, running UNICOS, which is in turn based on UNIX ("CRAY T90 systems run Cray Research's industry-leading [UNICOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20220222150048/http://0x07bell.net/WWWMASTER/CrayWWWStuff/prfolderproduct/T90_announce.950222.txt) operating system based on UNIX system V"); we can safely consider he ended doing so somewhere about 2005, when it was obsoleted by Cray X1; thus he most probably *wasn't* using Linux for this time (even though Linux already existed).

[image: BATCOMPUTER COMPONENTS]

c) Batman's Wayne Enterprise Mainframe (which is, most probably, used as *the* Batcomputer, since most of Batstuff is actually disguised as actual corporate property one or another) uses *n*x OS currently; see

[image: n-map]
[image: close-up]

```
Wayne Enterprise Mainframe:~ en$ nmap -v 192.168.23.10
```

with

```
username:path$
```

being the common command prompt of e.g. bash shell.

Since custom *n*x OSes are ATM the usual choice for supercomputers nowadays, mainly due to maintainability and security provided, it's quite obvious Batman would choose one for his Batcomputer. Hard to say if it's Linux or Unix/BSD clone due to lack of data - but saying it's a [Unix-like OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) is quite a good guess IMO.

(as as side note, I'd also assume it's a custom-tailored, highly personalized distribution - mostly because that's the way a power admin would go with his personal mainframe)

BTW:

> The batman-adv kernel module has been part of the official Linux kernel since 2.6.38.
>
> ("[B.A.T.M.A.N.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.A.T.M.A.N.)", *Wikipedia*) *chuckles*

Comment: UNIX was available well before 'the 1980s'.

Comment: @MilesRout: Quite so. A major clue is that all UNIX timestamps are calculated from 00:00 on 1 Jan 1970. According to this timeline it originated in 1969 and was "widely available outside of Bell Labs" by 1975: http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html

Comment: @MilesRout "beginning from 1980s, when UNIX systems actually appeared on the market" - I'm not saying that there weren't any UNIX before that date, only that they didn't contribute to a serious market share, quote: "During the late 1970s and 1980s, Unix developed into a standard operating system for academia." - first UNIX appeared ca. 1974; you're right it was available, you're wrong if you're trying to point my inacurracy, because there isn't one; being "wideliy available outside Bell Labs" doesn't mean anything, as it's the 7th ed, ca. 1979, that actually defined Unix in userspace.

Comment: @MilesRout remember that a movie/comic book has to use a hardware/software that is cryptic but *identifiable* to some degree; that's why many movies have snippets of actual code when there's something "hacky" going on. Also, providing an actual solution (e.g. UNIX) before most of movie/comix designers **knew that it existed** is something very unlikely.

Comment: and yes, I am aware that first versions of "UNIX" (not even functionally what we consider a UNIX today) were made before 1970; we could argue that a wheelbarrow was the first working UNIX implementation if you desire so... I mostly consider this "UNIX timeline" discussion a straw man agrument, as actually *reading* carefully the statement I've used is enough to show that your points are irrelevant to the statement at hand.

Comment: Nice answer, although I disagree that the WE mainframe is the bat computer. It's been shown the bat computer is local to the cave, and he has more than enough wealth to have his own personal super computer, which is a much more secure solution than using his companies mainframe.

Comment: Part c) also resembles [CISCO iOS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128899/are-router-firmware-based-on-linux). I think the username:path$ is pretty common for CLIs, even if they're custom-written.

Comment: What movie is that last screenshot from?

Comment: Unironically, nmap was put in that movie for _this exact question_!

Comment: @FaheemMitha Justice League: Doom.

Answer (score 41):

However, Batman does use [nmap](https://nmap.org/movies/) (bottom of the page).

[image: Computer screen displaying "Enter Passcode" and 5 boxes, overlaid with a text graphics popup labeled "Luther Corp Key Generator" also containing 5 boxes and a few lines of terminal output.] (click to zoom).

Therefore, it is entirely likely and possible that he uses a Linux distro of some sort.

Comment: nmap is available for all platforms.

Comment: It's interesting though that even Batman forgets what services are running on his own network.

Comment: nmap can be found on Windows, Linux, Unix and etc; http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html

Comment: the command line on the screenshot is clearly \*n*x - the 'username:path$' prompt shown on the shot is *rather uncommon* on Win boxes... with *rather uncommon* meaning *you won't see it until somebody decides to intentionally change his prompt in WinDOS to mislead you*

Comment: @vaxquis you should post that as an answer, since unlike this one about using nmap, that point actually does provide a pretty significant argument in favor of Linux on the Batcomputer.

Comment: This says "Wayne Enterprises Mainframe". Is that necessarily "Batman's computer"?

Comment: @vaxquis: Couldn't that also appear from an SSH session or if he's running Cygwin or MinGW?

Comment: @jpmc26 Batcomputer is obviously formally a "Wayne Enterprises Mainframe", since (probably) most of the Batstuff is disguised as Wayne Enterprises property one way another.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté **or** it could be BeOS, running VMware, running virtualized Windows 8.1 running Cygwin with Wine cmd with prompt carefully disguised as \*n*x one...